# Json to pie chart conversion error

Tags: javascript, database, json, google-visualization

I was trying to implement dynamic google pie chart.But while doing so it is connecting to the database via json call but I cannot implement a piechat ,.hence i am not able to get the value for the pie chart.

My Json data which i want to is as follows:-

```
function getHealthReport() 
{ 
  var dataString = {auth_token: sessionStorage.auth_token,};
  var mh_url = MH_HOST + '/reports/get_health_issues_report.json';

  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: mh_url,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) 
    {/*
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  <----- here i am getting piechart via  hardcoding
        function drawChart(){
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Task','Hours per Day'],
         ['Work',11],
         ['Eat',2],
         ['Commute',2]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('outer_tableDiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);}
        */
    },
    error: function (data) 
    {
        alert("fail");
    }    
  });  
}
```

can anyone please help.